# Finding the area and angle of a triangle with given points

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I am struggling with the following problem and would appreciate any help I can get.

Given the points $A=(1,2,3)$, $B=(-2,1,0)$ and $C=(2,0,1)$, I need to find:

(a) the area of the triangle formed by these points

(b) the angle at point $A$

Here is my attempt at solving the problem:

**(a)** To find the area of the triangle, I first need to find the length of its sides. Using the distance formula, I find that $AB = \sqrt{18}$, $AC = \sqrt{14}$, and $BC = \sqrt{26}$. Next, I use Heron's formula to find the area of the triangle:

$$
\begin{aligned}
s & =\frac{1}{2}(A B+A C+B C) \\
& =\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{18}+\sqrt{14}+\sqrt{26}) \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2(9+7+13+2 \sqrt{126}+2 \sqrt{117}+2 \sqrt{39})} \\
& \approx 6.222
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore, the area of the triangle is approximately 6.222 square units.

**(b)** To find the angle at point $A$, I need to use the dot product. Let $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ be the vectors from $A$ to $B$ and $C$, respectively. Then, the angle at point $A$ is given by:

$$
\theta=\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{\overrightarrow{A B} \cdot \overrightarrow{A C}}{|\overrightarrow{A B}||\overrightarrow{A C}|}\right)
$$

Computing the dot product and magnitudes, I get:

$$
\overrightarrow{A B} \cdot \overrightarrow{A C}=-5, \quad|\overrightarrow{A B}|=\sqrt{18}, \quad|\overrightarrow{A C}|=\sqrt{14}
$$

Substituting these values into the formula, I get:
$$
\theta=\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{-5}{\sqrt{18} \sqrt{14}}\right) \approx 1.744
$$

Comment: The distances are wrong. How did you get those numbers?

Comment: @Andrei You're right. If we have a vector $\mathbf{v} = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$ in three-dimensional space, its magnitude $|\mathbf{v}|$ is given by:

$$|\mathbf{v}| =\sqrt{v^{2}_{1}+v^{2}_{2}+v^{2}_{3}}$$

And we also know that the magnitude of a vector represents its length or size, and is always a non-negative real number.





So we have $$|\mathbf{v}| = \sqrt{v^{2}_{1}+v^{2}_{2}+v^{2}_{3}} =\sqrt{\left( -3\right)^{2}  +\left( -1\right)^{2}  +\left( -3\right)^{2}  } =\sqrt{19}$$

Comment: I was told the cross product of $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ is $(-4,-9,7)$, but I'm not sure how. But from that, the magnitude of $\vec{N}$ is $\sqrt{(-4)^2+(-9)^2+7^2}=\sqrt{146}$.

Comment: To calculate the cross product of two vectors, say $\vec{a}=\left(a_1, a_2, a_3\right)$ and $\vec{b}=\left(b_1,b_2,b_3\right)$, we first write them as column vectors:

$$
\vec{a}=\left(\begin{array}{l}
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
a_3
\end{array}\right) 
\quad \text { and } \quad \vec{b}
=\left(\begin{array}{l}
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
b_3
\end{array}\right)
$$
The cross product of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ is then given by the formula:
$$
\vec{a} \times \vec{b}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
a_2 b_3-a_3 b_2 \\
a_3 b_1-a_1 b_3 \\
a_1 b_2-a_2 b_1
\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: So, to find the cross product, you simply compute the determinant of the matrix

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3
\end{array}\right)
$$

where $\hat{i}$, $\hat{j}$, $\hat{k}$ are the unit vectors in the $x, y, z$ directions, and expand along the first row.

To find the angle at point $A$, we can use the dot product formula:

$$\vec{AB} \cdot \vec{AC} = |\vec{AB}| |\vec{AC}| \cos \theta$$

Plugging in the values we obtained earlier, we have:
$$(-3,-1,-3) \cdot (1,-2,-2) = \sqrt{19} \cdot \sqrt{15} \cdot \cos \theta$$

Comment: Simplifying, we get:

$$5 = \sqrt{285} \cos \theta$$

Solving for $\cos \theta$, we get:

$$\cos \theta = \frac{5}{\sqrt{285}}$$

Taking the inverse cosine of both sides, we get:

$$\theta = \cos^{-1} \left(\frac{5}{\sqrt{285}}\right) \approx 72.77^\circ$$

So the angle at point $A$ is approximately $72.77^\circ$.

Comment: To find the area of the triangle, we use the formula:
$$
\text { Area }=\frac{1}{2}|\overrightarrow{A B} \times \overrightarrow{A C}|
$$
From our previous calculations, we know that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \overrightarrow{A B}=(-3,-1,-3) \\
& \overrightarrow{A C}=(1,-2,-2)
\end{aligned}
$$
Taking the cross product of these vectors, we get:
$$
\overrightarrow{A B} \times \overrightarrow{A C}=(-4,-9,7)
$$
The magnitude of this vector is:
$$
|\overrightarrow{A B} \times \overrightarrow{A C}|=\sqrt{(-4)^2+(-9)^2+7^2}=\sqrt{146}
$$
Therefore, the area of the triangle is:

Comment: $$
\text {Area }=\frac{1}{2}|\overrightarrow{A B} \times \overrightarrow{A C}|=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{146}
$$
So, the final answer for the area of the triangle is $$\frac{\sqrt{146}}{2}$$

Comment: These look better. You know that you can just edit your question instead of writing so many comments?

Comment: @Andrei My teacher told me that we can't find the area using Heron's formula, do you know another way to solve it?

Comment: I see you use the cross product. That works. Alternatively, you can get the same answer by using your calculated $\theta$. The height from $B$ to $AC$ is $|AB|\sin\theta$, so the area is $\frac12|AB||AC|\sin\theta$